# webpack: how is it possible to have a javascript file query a backend without definint its URL in the compiled code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Im working on this react app using webpack.
When it compiles with the command webpack --mode production && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js

It uses a .env.prod to define a variable REACT_APP_BASE_URL which is a url to query the backend api.

It is defined in the webpack.config file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    app: "./src/index.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/frontend/js"),
    publicPath: "/static/frontend/js/",
    filename: "main.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ["static/frontend/js"],
    }),
    new Dotenv({ path: "./.env.prod" }),
```

How is it possible that neither REACT_APP_BASE_URL nor the actual value of this env variable appear in the main.js and 1.chunk.js and 2.chunk.js files generated during yarn prod?
How does the javascript code "knows" where to query the backend then?

Answer (score 0):

it's the dotenv plugin. - Dotenv is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables from a .env file into process.env. Storing configuration in the environment separate from code is based on The Twelve-Factor App methodology

Comment: I know dotenv is retrieving environment variable, but i dont have any process.env file created by dotenv or webpack.